# Hymn of lord Shiva by Ma Saraswati

Tags: shiva, stotra, saraswati, hymn

Has devi Saraswati composed any hymn herself on Lord Shiva or on any other deity, if yes please provide a source?

This is inspired by the couplet of shiva mahimna stotr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `Has Devi Saraswati composed any hymn herself on Lord Shiva or`

#### `on [any other deity]?`

There's one from the Brahmavaivarta-Purāṇa - Brahma-khaṇḍa - Adhyāya 3 [Śloka 60-64]

Quoting the Sanskrit Verses from the [Sanskrit Documents website](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_vishhnu/krishnastotrasarasvatIBVP.html)

##### This is told by goddess Sarasvatī in obeisance to Śrī Kṛṣṇa

> ##### Śrī Kṛṣṇa stotraṃ - brahmavaivarta-purāṇe Sarasvatīkṛtam
>
> सरस्वत्युवाच ।
>
> रासमण्डलमध्यस्थं रासोल्लाससमुत्सुकम् । रत्नसिंहासनस्थं च
> रत्नभूषणभूषितम् ॥ १॥
>
> रासेश्वरं ऱासकरं वरं ऱासेश्वरीश्वरम् । ऱसाधिष्ठातृदेवं च वन्दे
> ऱासविनोदिनम् ॥ २॥
>
> रासायासपरिश्रान्तं रासरासविहारिणम् । रासोत्सुकानां गोपीनां कान्तं
> शान्तं मनोहरम् ॥ ३॥
>
> प्रणम्य च तमित्युक्त्वा प्रह्यष्टवदना सती । उवास सा सकामा च
> रत्नसिंहासने वरे ॥ ४॥
>
> इति वाणीकृतं स्तोत्रं प्रातरुत्थाय यः पठेत् । बुद्धिमान्धनवान्सोऽपि
> विद्यावान्पुत्रवान्सदा ॥ ५॥
>
> इति ब्रह्मावैवर्ते सरस्वतीकृतं श्रीकृष्णस्तोत्रम् ।

One may read the English Translation from [here](https://archive.org/details/brahma-vaivarta-purana-all-four-kandas-english-translation/page/n13/mode/2up?view=theater),
and the Hindi Translation from [here](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.424443/page/n53/mode/2up).

Answer (score 2):

A short hymn by Maa Saraswati and all other devis to Lord Shiva for the resurrection of Kama Deva.

**Shiva Maha Puranam.**

**Chapter 51 - The resuscitation of Kāma.**

**Section 2.3 - Rudra-saṃhitā (3): Pārvatī-khaṇḍa.**

> *रतिरोदनमाकर्ण्य सरस्वत्यादयः स्त्रियः ।
> रुरुदुस्सकला देव्यः प्रोचुर्दीनतरं वचः ॥ ११ ॥*
>
> *॥ देव्य ऊचुः ।
> भक्तवत्सलनामा त्वं दीनबन्धुर्दयानिधिः ।
> काम जीवय सोत्साहां रति कुरु नमोऽस्तु ते ॥ १२ ॥*

> *11. On hearing the lamentation of Rati, Sarasvatī and other celestial ladies wept bitterly and spoke in piteous tones.*
>
> ***The celestial ladies said:—***
> *12. Obeisance to you, O lord, you are known as favourably disposed to your devotees. You are friend of the distressed, storehouse of mercy. Resuscitate the cupid. Make Rati jubilant.*

I hope this clarifies your queries.